# 1-d family of the solutions of the matrix equation $diag (U^T A U)=F$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, linear-transformations

Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ and $F$ is a real vector s.t.
$$\operatorname{trace}(A)=\sum_{p=1}^3 F_p.$$
Find an orthonormal matrix $U$ ($U^{\tau}U=UU^{\tau}=I$) s.t.
$$\operatorname{diag}(U^{\tau}AU)=F,$$
or explicitly
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^3 U_{ip}A_{ij}U_{jp}=F_p.$$
It is well known that an orthogonal $3\times3$ matrix forms a $3-D$ manifold. Naively, one expects that these $3$ additional constraints allow finding a unique point. As explained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330351/reconstruct-a-matrix-from-its-traces), one equation is redundant, and therefore one expects a $1$-parameter solution to the problem in general case. One can also imagine a case when there is a unique solution, namely when the problem of finding a $3-D$ rotation can be reduced to $2-D$ rotation, which is parameterized by only one angle.

My question is the following: how can the $1$-dimensional general solution be parametrized, what are the exact conditions of having 0-dimensional solutions, and when the solutions do not exist.

It is tempting to bring this problem in correspondence of finding a matrix congruence (it has a solution only when the two matrices have the same [inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia)) such as discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78106/solving-a-quadratic-matrix-equation/145764#145764), and which can be solved by the Gram–Schmidt process. However, there are some differences such as we impose from the beginning a certain structure of the solution and impose fewer constraints.